# Outlook calendar won't sync in Google

Tags: google-calendar, sharing, outlook.com-calendar

I want the events from an Outlook calendar to show up in my Google calendar. I control both calendars.

In Outlook, I can share the calendar with a URL. In Gcal, I go to `Settings`, `Add calendar`, `From URL`, paste in the Outlook URL and the calendar is added. The events show up after a sync taking a few seconds.

However, when I add new events on the Outlook side, they don't show up in Gcal. If I delete the calendar from Gcal, and add again, the new events also show up. But I don't want to keep deleting and re-adding it every time there's a new event.

How can I get it to automatically sync? Alternatively, is there an easier way to force a manual sync?